# Overwrite Last N Days from column in R to Snowflake

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbi, sparkr

For example purposes, I am using the tidyquant dataset.

```
install.packages('tidyquant')
library(tidyquant)
library(data.table)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
# Downloading Apple price using quantmod
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 30
last.date <- Sys.Date()

getSymbols("AAPL", from = first.date,
           to = last.date,warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)
AAPL<-data.frame(AAPL)
AAPL<- setDT(AAPL, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
colnames(AAPL)[1] <- "DATE"
AAPL$RUNDATE<-AAPL$DATE
head(AAPL)

         DATE AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted      RUNDATE
1: 2021-03-19    119.90    121.43   119.68     119.99   185023200        119.99   2021-03-19
2: 2021-03-22    120.33    123.87   120.26     123.39   111912300        123.39   2021-03-22
3: 2021-03-23    123.33    124.24   122.14     122.54    95467100        122.54   2021-03-23
4: 2021-03-24    122.82    122.90   120.07     120.09    88530500        120.09   2021-03-24
5: 2021-03-25    119.54    121.66   119.00     120.59    98844700        120.59   2021-03-25
6: 2021-03-26    120.35    121.48   118.92     121.21    93958900        121.21   2021-03-26
```

Here is my goal, I have already figured out how to upload this dataset into snowflake using R from Databricks using the following command:

```
sparkr.sdf <- SparkR::createDataFrame(AAPL)

SparkR::write.df(
  df = sparkr.sdf,
  source = "snowflake",
  mode = "overwrite",
  sfUrl = "<snowflake-url>",
  sfUser = user,
  sfPassword = password,
  sfDatabase = "<snowflake-database>",
  sfSchema = "<snowflake-schema>",
  sfWarehouse = "<snowflake-cluster>",
  dbtable = "AAPL_table"
)
```

However, I want to run this daily and upload the latest date's pull (last 30 days), append and overwrite the last 30 days from the RunDate column.

My idea is to use the same query above moving forward except change the rundate column to today's date. `AAPL$RUNDATE<-Sys.Date()` daily. That way when I run this, I can subtract 30 days from this new `AAPL$RUNDATE` and only keep anything within a 30 day timeframe of the AAPL$RUNDATE moving forward.

I saw this code but I don't see an option to set the lookback limit

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(snowflake.conn,"use schema schemaname") # strange this is required

dbWriteTable(snowflake.conn, 'tablename', df, append = T, overwrite = F, verbose = T)
```

or this
[source:](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/snowflake-r.html)

```
# Write table
sparklyr.sdf <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)

sparklyr.sdf %>%
  spark_write_source(
   sc = sc,
   mode = "overwrite",
   source = "snowflake", 
   options = sf_options
  )
```

The idea would be I run this data pull each day for the last 30 days of data instead of the full time period and append to the existing dataset.

Has anyone done something like this before, would really appreciate any help with this and let me know if you need any more clarity on what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: What does *"append and overwrite"* mean? My interpretation is that those actions are mutually exclusive. I think you want to append new data and remove data outside of 30 days, is that right? Is there a reason you cannot keep all (even old) data and just handle the "last 30 days" part within the query?

Comment: Hi @r2evans you are correct, these are mutually exclusive. However, when I overwrite I want to only overwrite the last 30 days of data and keep the historicals. This is why I made the suggestion of doing both append and overwrite. I'm taking a look at your answer below now. Thanks for the help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you run your code to get the new data and store in a variable named `AAPL`, then

```r
AAPL$RUNDATE <- Sys.Date()
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, AAPL, append = TRUE)
```

From here, I think you have two options:

1. Remove data that is more than 30 days old. After you append new data to the table, then run

   ```r
   DBI::dbExecute(conn,
     "delete from AAPL_table
      where DATEDIFF(day, RUNDATE, CURRENT_DATE()) > 30")
   ```

   (Formed using examples from [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html) and [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_date.html).)

   As an alternative, in case you don't run that clearing *today*, you may prefer to use the max observed `RUNDATE` in the table instead of today's date, in which case you might use

   ```r
   maxdate <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select max(RUNDATE) as maxdate from AAPL_table")$maxdate
   if (length(maxdate) && !anyNA(maxdate)) {
     DBI::dbExecute(conn,
       "delete from AAPL_table where DATEDIFF(day, RUNDATE, ?) > 30", params = list(maxdate))
   }
   ```
2. *Keep* the old data in the table, and whenever you retrieve it from your snowflake instance, only retrieve the last 30 days worth:

   ```r
   x <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn,
     "select ... from AAPL_table where RUNDATE >= ?", params = list(Sys.Date()))
   ```

(Caveat: I don't have snowflake, so this is untested. I tested the premise of it in sql server without problem, and verified that at least the two sql functions are supported.)

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look and test this out this upcoming weekend

Comment: This was helpful thanks. I went about it alittle differently but this was a good start to answering my question. I did this instead: `Delete from old table as A using (select distinct DATE, MAX(RUN_DATE) AS MRD
FROM new table group by 1,2) AS MAX_RUN_DATE WHERE        
MAX_RUN_DATE.DATE = A.DATE AND 
MAX_RUN_DATE.MRD >= A.RUN_DATE`